# What does "ik" signify in Gmail URLs?

Tags: url, gmail, email-attachments, download

This is the URL:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/ui=2&ik=88144a6954&view=att&th=15a0a00d6a767b78&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_iyrgwhgr0&zw
```

It is the URL for downloading Gmail attachments.

I have figured out that `ik` value is user specific, but I am not able to connect it with user ID or something.

Comment: `ik` value is defined in the page source as an element of `GLOBALS` object right before the user email. You can extract it easily if that's your objective here.

Comment: thanks for your help                                                                                                 the index of ik is 9 in the GLOBALS

Comment: I think it'd be more reliable to find the email element and get the previous one, just in case.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you explain exactly where the GLOBALS can be found ? thank you .

Answer (score -2):

The `ik` value can be found at the 9th index in the `GLOBALS` array, which you can see by examining the page source. It is right before the user email.